# Running a java script with a java program

Tags: java, selenium

I have a selenium script written in java with the following structure

Script.java

```
@before
-----Some methods------

@Test
-----Some methods------

@after
-----Some methods------
```

and i have a main java program with structure

Main.java

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    //Here i have to write the logic to run the above script
}
```

in which i have a main method i have to run the above mentioned script from this java program, how it can be done. as i am a newbie for java so any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using unit test framework like `JUnit` or `TestNg` Then the methods mentioned under `annotations` like `@Test` ,`@Before` and so on are independent itself. Their execution order is as per preferance in that framework itself. Main method not required here.

So in your case if you have done code using these methods using any `TestNG` or `JUnit` then have to use like following -

```
class Myclass
{

      @Before
      public void methodA()
     {
           // Your code
     }

     @Test
     public void methodB()
     {
         // your code
     }
    @After
    public void methodC
   {
          // your code
   }
}
```

And Run your class like `Run As` > `TestNG Test` if you are using `TestNG framework`

Comment: No i am not using TestNG or JUnit and both of these code snippets are from different packages. the script is already written i just need to invoke this script programmatically from a different package

Comment: then import that package where you want to access and  do access the method by creating object of that class. in your example 1. import  `Script.java` class package in  `Main.java` class's package. 2. Create an object of `Script` class under main method and then access method of `Script` class using that object. 3. Run `Main.java` class

Comment: Thats the problem i have around 20 methods in Script.java and they are ordered using before , test, after so i don't want to call every method from the main.java. i just wanted to know that is there a way so that i can run complete script.java from main.java

Comment: Whishky, It sounds like your "script" was written with a testing framework in mind, but it is not clear which one.  Perhaps you can find out by looking at the `import` statements.  Then, to run it, as it was written as a testing module, you need to invoke the testing framework from the `main.java` file and have the testing framework load and run the script.   Doing something else will likely not give you the same results as the script intended.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations in java needs a package like junit ,testNg or cucumber - jvm where

> @Test ,@Before ,@After

could find a way to be run.So you cannot find an answer in java to run them as these annotations are not part of Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think only way to run testNG based script is to create a suite of testNG.xml file and do the execution of suite in main class.Try this code

```
    List<String> suitesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    TestListener listener = new TestListener();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    testng.setOutputDirectory("outputfoldername");
    suitesList.add("testng.xml");
    testng.setTestSuites(suitesList);
    testng.addListener(listener);
    testng.run();
```